# Modificar etiqueta de gráfico circular 3D Google Charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, php7, php5, google-chart-api

Estoy generando un gráfico circular 3D con la API de Google Charts, JQuery y PHP, estos son mis códigos:

**PHP:**

```
<?php
  $ventas = Venta::getTotalVentasMes($ano);
    
  function Mes($mes)
  {
    switch($mes)
    {
       case 1: return "Ene";
       case 2: return "Feb";
       case 3: return "Mar";
       case 4: return "Abr";
       case 5: return "May";
       case 6: return "Jun";
       case 7: return "Jul";
       case 8: return "Ago";
       case 9: return "Sep";
       case 10: return "Oct";
       case 11: return "Nov";
       case 12: return "Dic";
    }
  }
    
  $array = array();     
    
  if(is_array($ventas))
  {
     foreach($ventas as $venta)
     {
        $mes = Mes($venta['mes']);
        $array['cols'][] = array('type' => 'string'); 
        $array['rows'][] = array('c' => array(array('v' => $mes), array('v'=>(float)$venta['total'])));
     }
    
     echo json_encode($array);
  }
  else
    echo 0;
?>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function generarGrafica(ano)
{
    google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      
    function drawChart() {
        var jsonData = $.ajax({
                url: "../includes/acciones/ventas/getVentasJSON.php",
                data: "ano=" + ano,
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                async: false
        }).responseText;
        
        if(jsonData != 0)
        {
          var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

          var options = {
           title: 'Ventas Mensuales ' + ano,
           is3D: true,
          };

          var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart_3d'));
          chart.draw(data, options);    
        }
    }
}
```

Lo que quiero es formatear el texto de las etiquetas del gráfico
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir que el valor en este ejemplo 100 se vea con formato de moneda $100.00.

Como puedo hacer eso??